# Spring Roo pagination with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pagination, spring-roo

I'm using Spring roo to make a web app, and I'm using hibernate with a mysql database and twitter bootstrap for the css, and all I need to finish my application is pagination, but I have no idea where to start.  I've been looking up and reading about spring pagination, but most of the resources are using spring data, and I don't think I'm using that.  If anyone can just give me an idea of where to start or any resources to read that would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the [gvNIX project](http://www.gvnix.org/en/index.html)? This includes features like bootstrap integration and JQuery Datatables widget in AJAX mode (and much more: jasperReports, Hibernate-Envers, Hibernate-Spatial, Leaflet,... )

This a [example project](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/tree/master/quickstart-app) and its [on-line demo](http://petclinic-gvnix.rhcloud.com/login). And [this is with the *Geo* feature](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/tree/master/quickstart-geo-app)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I haven't heard of that, I will check it out and let you know how it goes